# C++ How to prefix uint16_t in front of uint8_t *buffer

Tags: c++

Here is how I create my message with FlatBuffers and how I send it over TCP with Boost ASIO.

```
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;
auto email = builder.CreateString("test@asd.dg");
auto password = builder.CreateString("test");
auto loginRequest = Vibranium::CreateLoginRequest(builder,email,password);
builder.FinishSizePrefixed(loginRequest);
size_t size = builder.GetSize();
uint8_t *buf = builder.GetBufferPointer();
//And here I am sending it with Boost ASIO.
boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(buf,size));
```

What I would like to do is get a value of this enum:

```
enum ServerOpcode : uint16_t{
    SMSG_AUTH_CONNECTION_RESPONSE                    = 0x001,
    SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST                               = 0x002,
    SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE_TEST                 = 0xA99,
};
```

Let's say like so:

```
ServerOpcode opc;
opc = ServerOpcode::SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST;
```

And prepend `opc` in front of `buf*`.

As `uint16_t` is fixed size than on the receiving end i'll know that the `ServerOpcdode` is always kept in the first two bytes.

So how can I prepend `opc` infron of `buf` is it even possible and how?

P.S.
Note that the `file_indetifier` of FlatBuffers is not a solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allocate an intermediate buffer.

```
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;
auto email = builder.CreateString("test@asd.dg");
auto password = builder.CreateString("test");
auto loginRequest = Vibranium::CreateLoginRequest(builder,email,password);
builder.FinishSizePrefixed(loginRequest);
size_t size = builder.GetSize();
uint8_t *buf = builder.GetBufferPointer();
uint8_t *actualBuffer = new uint8_t[size + 2];
actualBuffer[1] = (code >> 8);
actualBuffer[0] = (code&0xFF);
memcpy(actualBuffer + 2, buf, size);
//And here I am sending it with Boost ASIO.
boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(actualBuffer, size + 2));
delete[] actualBuffer;
```

I've chosen to encode the uint16_t code as Big Endian, as is good form for any sort of network communication I am familiar with, however you can of course also just do a `memcpy(actualBuffer, &code, 2);`, at the risk of not knowing the endianess.

Comment: Thank you. The encoding of FlatBuffers is little-endian. Can you please adjust the answer ?

Comment: I assume you mean like this, then?

Comment: I am not sure if it worked. Can you check this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64442518/c-unable-to-get-prefixed-uint16-t-header