# C++ - Unable to get prefixed uint16_t header

Tags: c++

Here is how I form up my message with FlatBuffers and how I send it over via Boost ASIO.

```
enum ServerOpcode : uint16_t{
    SMSG_AUTH_CONNECTION_RESPONSE                    = 0x001,
    SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST                               = 0x002,
    SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE_TEST                 = 0xA99,
};

ServerOpcode opc;
opc = ServerOpcode::SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE_TEST;

flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;
auto email = builder.CreateString("test@abv.bg");
auto password = builder.CreateString("passHerepassHerepassHerepassHereZzpa");
auto loginRequest = Vibranium::CreateLoginRequest(builder,email,password);
builder.FinishSizePrefixed(loginRequest);
size_t size = builder.GetSize();
uint8_t *buf = builder.GetBufferPointer();

uint8_t *actualBuffer = new uint8_t[size + 2];
actualBuffer[1] = (opc >> 8);
actualBuffer[0] = (opc&0xFF);
memcpy(actualBuffer + 2, buf, size);


boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(actualBuffer,size + 2));
```

So what I basically want to achieve is to prepend a uint16_t header infront of the flatbuffers message.

Here is the structure I use.

```
class Packet {
public:
    Packet()
    {
    }
    static const int header_size = 2;
    static const int body_size_in_bytes = 4;
    std::vector<std::byte> header_buffer;
    std::vector<std::byte> size_buffer;
    uint16_t headerCode{0};
    uint32_t body_size{0};
    std::vector<std::byte> body_buffer;
    void PreparePacket(ServerOpcode serverOpcode, std::string message);
};
```

And here is how I try to read the header on server side:

```
void Vibranium::Client::read_header() {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    _packet.header_buffer.resize(_packet.header_size);
    boost::asio::async_read(socket,
    boost::asio::buffer(_packet.header_buffer.data(), _packet.header_size),
    [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec,std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if ((boost::asio::error::eof == ec) || (boost::asio::error::connection_reset == ec))
        {
            Disconnect();
        }
        else
        {
            std::memcpy(&_packet.header_buffer, &_packet.header_buffer[0], sizeof (_packet.headerCode));
            std::cout << "Header Code: " << _packet.headerCode << std::endl;
            //read_size();
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately this gives me output of:

```
Header Code: 0
```

Why and how can I get the prepended 2 byte header correctly? Where is my mistake and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there any reason in particular, why you would declare a vector for a fixed with data field? Why not write `uint8_t header_buffer[2];` Other than that, I don't have any experience with Boost, however when it comes to networking, I tend to suggest first looking at the data Wireshark captures to see whether the data you are expecting is actually being sent.

Comment: Oh and you're copying from header_buffer to header_buffer.
You may want to change that to `std::memcpy(&_packet.headerCode, &_packet.header_buffer[0], sizeof (_packet.headerCode));`

Comment: Yes that was it @RefugnicEternium. Please make an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I was already at it, but then the phone rang. :)

Comment: To answer why I use resize of the vector it's because it is `std::vector<std::byte> header_buffer;`

Comment: I was not asking about the `resize`, I was asking 'Why use a vector in the first place, instead of `std::byte header_buffer[2]`'. But of course it's your choice.

Comment: Note that your header reading code works only on little-endian CPU's. It will get the wrong value on big endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in your 'copy step', you are copying from source to target. (The compiler might actually notify you of that).

If you change your memcpy to `std::memcpy(&_packet.headerCode, &_packet.header_buffer[0], sizeof (_packet.headerCode));`, it should start working.